# How can I manipulate the playing video on a CAF receiver?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I have a new CAF receiver and would love to be able to manipulate the video using javascript but I'm unable to get the video element using javascript. Is there some way to do this if using `<cast-media-player id="player"></cast-media-player>`?

Answer (score 0):

Any operations on the video element on a chromecast device isn't technically feasible. Firstly, the video pipeline is handled by the SOC. Also, the CPU of the device doesn't have the processing power to do any video operations in real time.

Comment: I was actually more interested on doing operations on an image and I noticed images are just shown inside the `<video>` tag. Simple things like zoom in and out, rotate.